# Avoid repetition in XSLT template rules using XSLT 1.0

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

Given the following XML document:

```
<document>
  <a>123</a>
  <foo_1>true</foo_1>
  <foo_2>false</foo_2>
  <foo_3>true</foo_3>
  <foo_4>true</foo_4>
  <foo_5>false</foo_5>
  <b/>
  <bar_1>false</bar_1>
  <bar_2>false</bar_2>
  <bar_3>true</bar_3>
  <bar_4>false</bar_4>
  <bar_5>true</bar_5>
  <c>some text</c>
</document>
```

I want to transform this document by eliminating all enumerated elements containing `false` and by converting all enumerated elements containing `true` into the form `<prefix_n>value</prefix_n>`, where `value` is the number after the underscore.

For the example given above the result should look like this:

```
<document>
  <a>123</a>
  <foo_n>1</foo_n>
  <foo_n>3</foo_n>
  <foo_n>4</foo_n>
  <b/>
  <bar_n>3</bar_n>
  <bar_n>5</bar_n>
  <c>some text</c>
</document>
```

For this I am using the following transformation, which works fine.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

  <!-- standard copy template -->
  <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*" />
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="*[substring(name(), 1, 4) = 'foo_']">
    <xsl:if test=". = 1 or . = 'true'">
      <xsl:element name="foo_n">
        <xsl:value-of select="substring-after(name(), 'foo_')"/>
      </xsl:element>
    </xsl:if>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="*[substring(name(), 1, 4) = 'bar_']">
    <xsl:if test=". = 1 or . = 'true'">
      <xsl:element name="bar_n">
        <xsl:value-of select="substring-after(name(), 'bar_')"/>
      </xsl:element>
    </xsl:if>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Now I'm facing the problem that I have to deal with a multitude of different prefixes, not just `foo_` and `bar_`.

Is there a way to turn the template rules into a named template where I can pass in the prefix as an argument, thereby avoiding to write a lot of repetitive template rules?

Comment: Do you want (or need) to list all the possible prefixes at all? Isn't the presence of the `_` separator enough?

Comment: Unfortunately not. I have other elements like `a_b` in the document as well. But the names of all elements that need to be transformed (and only those) end with the regular expression  `_[0-9]+`, if that is of any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one way you could look at it:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="*[starts-with(name(), 'foo_') or starts-with(name(), 'bar_')]">
    <xsl:if test=". = 1 or . = 'true'">
        <xsl:element name="{substring-before(name(), '_')}-n">
            <xsl:value-of select="substring-after(name(), '_')"/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

---

Here's another:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="*[contains(translate(name(), '123456789', '000000000'), '_0')]">
    <xsl:if test=". = 1 or . = 'true'">
        <xsl:variable name="prefix" select="substring-before(translate(name(), '123456789', '000000000'), '_0')" />
        <xsl:element name="{$prefix}-n">
            <xsl:value-of select="substring(name(), string-length($prefix) + 2)"/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This last one should work with *any* prefix followed by `_[1-9]` - including prefixes that contain an additional underscore and including prefixes that contain other prefixes.

Comment: Thank you. But AFAICT this won't work for for elements like `foo_bar_1`?

Comment: Your own code - which you said is working fine - will not work for `foo_bar_1`. It is possible to *make* it work (with some effort, as there is no regex in XSLT 1.0).

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand why my code shouldn't work for the prefix `foo_bar_`. I just tried it and it seems to work fine when I add the missing template rule.

Comment: What you don't see is the error message indicating a template conflict. And you will get a different result if you change the order of the templates.

Comment: Yes, of course! `foo_` and `foo_bar_` have the same prefix. My bad.

Comment: I just checked. The prefixes I'm dealing with are all unique (no prefix is a prefix of another prefix) but they do contain one ore more underscores.

Comment: I'm impressed by your creative use of the string functions. This is exactly what I need. Big thank you!

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to turn the template rules into a named template where I can pass in the prefix as an argument

Well, sure:

```
<xsl:template name="if-true">
  <xsl:param name="prefix"/>
  <xsl:if test=". = 1 or . = 'true'">
    <xsl:element name="{concat($prefix, 'n')}">
      <xsl:value-of select="substring-after(name(), $prefix)"/>
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>

<!-- example using the above: -->
<xsl:template match="*[starts-with(name(), 'foo_')]">
  <xsl:call-template name="if-true">
    <xsl:with-param name="prefix" select="'foo_'"/>
  </xsl:call-template>
</xsl:template>
```

But it's not clear whether that would really achieve your objective:

> , thereby avoiding to write a lot of repetitive template rules?

because you would still need a bunch of templates of the second kind to match the specific elements you want to transform.  A solution along the lines @michael.hor257k suggested, that avoids duplication by making the same template match all the elements you want to transform, is a better alternative.

Comment: Better than my approach; at least I would have to specify the prefix only twice instead of three times. (And of course I should have used `starts-with()` from the beginning.) But actually I was hoping that I could get away with listing each prefix only once.